# Are there any sample GUI and FEST code that might help in understanding the framework?

Tags: java, gui-testing, fest

I have been reading a lot and looking at the code to understand how FEST works. Unforunately I could'n find that many sample code online other than:

fest.codehaus.org/Getting+Started

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2007/jw-07-fest.html

http://www.slideshare.net/Softwarecentral/easy-gui-testing-with-fest

If you can give some examples or links that would be very helpful.
Thank You

Comment: I am in the same situation. Most of the examples are a bit old. Some are outdated or even contradictory

Comment: I am also having the same problem. I'm not getting a test up and running using any of the examples at CodeHaus. Did you ever find any more help on the web, Mehmet? I know a new release is imminent, but it is not clear the documentation will be different or improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Swing Module](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Swing+Module) has detailed information here.